# What is wrong with this https.request example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecma

When I try [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) it never returns anything.

```
const https = require('https')

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  //      key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  //      cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out why it doesn't work?

When I have a working example, I would like to get the cert+key working. So this the first step in that attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not exactly like the sample from the documentation, which works.

Shouldn't you call the `end()` function on the request object so that the request is actually completely sent?

I think that's what's missing in your snippet. Without that, the stream is not closed and the request keeps pending for more, and you never receive a response since your request is not over.